# MVC model one value is null in POST but not in GET method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I've very simple one record to update using LINQ. But when I fetch that record in `GET` method the record successfully get fetched; however, in `POST` method value GrantNumber of the **same** record show as NULL as shown in figures 1 and 2 below. Same is true for the primary key `S_CPT_RCId` that is showing different values in GET and POST. **NOTE**: Snapshot in figure1 is taken in the second line of GET method, and figure 2 is from the input parameter of POST method (just before the UPDATE) :

**Controller**:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> TestMethod()
{
    var qry = _context.AnnualReview.Where(g => g.GrantNumber == grantNum).SingleOrDefault();
    return View(qry);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> TestMethod(AnnualReview test)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var oRec = _context.AnnualReview.Where(g => g.GrantNumber == test.GrantNumber).SingleOrDefault();
        oRec.RC_1a = test.RC_1a;
        oRec.RC_1b = test.RC_1b;
        oRec.RC_2a = test.RC_2a;
        oRec.RC_2b = test.RC_2b;
        oRec.RC_3a = test.RC_3a;
        oRec.RC_3b = test.RC_3b;
        oRec.RC_4a = test.RC_4a;
        oRec.RC_5a = test.RC_5a;
        oRec.RC_5b = test.RC_5b;
        oRec.RC_6a = test.RC_6a;
        oRec.RC_6b = test.RC_6b;

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("TestMethod2");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("TestMethod");
}
```

**Snapshot of record return from GET method (debug mode)**:

[image]

**Snapshot of the SAME record in the POST method (debug mode)**:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your view?

Comment: In your view these property names match exactly with that of name attribute of control? Confirm that, default model binder looks for exact property name.

Comment: Assuming that you are doing a page submit ratger than ajax post, probable issue is that your view might not be having elements with name `GrantNumber` and `S_CPR_RCid`. Try having two hidden fields for this with corresponding name and value

Comment: what is the content of `AnnualReview` class? it could be that those fields are just private

Comment: @Developer Everyone helped me identify the issue. I think `@Developer` explained it best. I'm marking as `Answer` the response from `@BadDub` since he first asked the right question asking me to post the view. Indeed -as `@Developer` and others indicated - missing the two fields in question from the `View` was the cause of the issue. I've **Upvoted** other's responses/comments, as well, since they deserve it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not allowing the GrantNumber and the RCId to be edited using inputs in the view, then you need to add @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.GrantNumber) and @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.S_CPT_RCId) to your view so that they are passed back in the POST.

Also make sure these are inside your form.

Answer (score 3):

GrantNumber and S_CPT_RCId may not be present inside the form.